# PowerMockito doThrow not throwing exception

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am attempting to test for a thrown exception but the code continues on to return true instead of catching the exception and returning false.

Test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class TestClass 
{

private Argument arg;
private static Class1 mockObj1;
private static Class2 mockObj2;

@BeforeClass
public static void initialSetup()
{
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class1.class);
    mockObj1 = PowerMockito.mock(Class1.class);
    mockObj2 = PowerMockito.mock(Class2.class);
}

@Before
public void setupForEachTest()
{   
    arg = new Argument();
}   

@Test
public void testUpdate() throws RemoteException
{
    PowerMockito.when(Class1.getDefault()).thenReturn(mockObj1);
    PowerMockito.when(mockObj1.getClass2()).thenReturn(mockObj2);
    PowerMockito.doThrow(new RemoteException()).when(mockObj2).save(arg);
    assertFalse(rule.update(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

method to be tested

```
public boolean update(params)
{   
    try
    {           
      Class1.getDefault().getClass2().save(args);
    }

    catch(RemoteException e)
    {
        Log.error(this, e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I get an assertion error each time I try to run this I have tried both the do throw and thenThrow methods any help with this would be appreciated.

edit:

StackTrace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:68)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:79)
    at package.TestClass.testUpdate(TestClass.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

save method

```
public abstract int save(Argument paramarg)
throws RemoteException;
```

Comment: have you tried adding `catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.error(this, e);
        return false;
    }` ? maybe it's some other kind of exception?

Comment: Can you update your question to include (a) a stacktrace showing the ""assertion error" and (b) the implementation of `Class2.save()`.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the stack trace

Comment: Just for the record: why do you "prepare for test" for Class2" ( you are not mocking a static call in that class). Why do use BeforeClass - that code could well go into your @Before setup method.

Comment: To start, I would recommend ensuring that you are getting back the expected mock objects. The simplest way to do that would probably be to run the test in debug mode with a few breakpoints.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You put up some code, but you are leaving out other details. I am simply not convinced that you gave us all the relevant detail. Thus: step back, and build a **true** [mcve] that we will be able to run ourselves, worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a bit confused by the question. Specifically:

- The test instances `arg = new Argument()` in a `@Before` method which implies that `arg` is relevant to each test.
- The provided `update()` method declaration looks like this: `public boolean update(params)`, it does not define the type for the `params` argument.
- The question also provides this implementation for the `save()` method: `int save(Argument paramarg) throws RemoteException;` which implies that `Argument arg` is passed into `update()` so by extension the type of `params` must be `Argument` but the test case calls `rule.update(null, null, null, ...)`

Anwyay, given these assumptions:

- The update() method is:

  ```
  public boolean update(Argument params) {
      try {
          Class1.getDefault().getClass2().save(params);
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```
- The save() method is;

  ```
  save(Argument arg) throws RemoteException
  ```

The following test passes:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Class1.class})
public class ATestClass {

    private Argument arg;
    private Class1 mockObj1;
    private Class2 mockObj2;

    @Before
    public void initialSetup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class1.class);

        mockObj1 = Mockito.mock(Class1.class);

        mockObj2 = Mockito.mock(Class2.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setupForEachTest() {
        arg = new Argument();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() throws RemoteException {
        PowerMockito.when(Class1.getDefault()).thenReturn(mockObj1);
        Mockito.when(mockObj1.getClass2()).thenReturn(mockObj2);

        Mockito.when(mockObj2.save(Mockito.any(Argument.class))).thenThrow(new RemoteException());

        Assert.assertFalse(update(arg));
    }
}
```

Note: you only need to use PowerMock to take care of this invocation: `Class1.getDefault()`, all other mocked invocations are neither static nor final so Mockito suffices.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, I'm still new to stack overflow, java and junit testing in general so I tried to format the question as best I could. Your assumptions were pretty much correct only I had arg as a local variable within the class. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @sharkzooka for future reference you could follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to create a minimal, verifiable, complete example. Another way to think about it is to consider what information would **you** want to be given if **you** were asked to diagnose the issue. Code which can be easily copied-n-pasted into your own IDE and can reliably reproduce the problem is the best starting point.